# How do I Increment a React Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Introduction

Hello, I'm trying to build a counter component for my online store, but I'm having trouble getting with it to function correctly.

### Problem

From my understanding is that the `count` value will not increment because it remains in the same instance, and the value is never changed in the parent component just re-rendered. Declaring a variable and trying to increment locally in the `addOne()` method also is causing the value not to change.

### Question

Is there something I'm not understanding about instances and how they work, can anyone give me some suggestions?

```
class ParentComponentClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const test = "Is anything printing?";
    let count = 0;
    return (
      <div>
        <QuantityCounter_CheckoutButton count={count} />
        <Test test={test} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class QuantityCounter_CheckoutButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
  }
  addOne() {
    let qtyCount = this.props.count;
    qtyCount++;
    console.log(qtyCount);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" id="bazuka_add" onClick={this.addOne}>
          <i className="material-icons ">add_circle_outline</i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="bazuka_remove" onClick={this.minusOne}>
          <i className="material-icons ">remove_circle_outline</i>
        </a>
        <p>qty:</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I know you have marked this as answered but I want to explain this concept to you.This is a simple but very important concept to grab.

Just imagine two functions

```
function manipulateCounter(count){
    count++
    console.log(count)
}

function counterContainer(){
    let countVariable = 0;
    manipulateCounter(countVariable);
    manipulateCounter(countVariable);
    manipulateCounter(countVariable);
    console.log(count);
}
```

I have a container which calls an incrementer. Now my target is to increment the 'countVariable'. But the way I have done it; my incrementing logic is broken. This is because by passing the 'value' via function I am just passing a copy of the value but not a way to manipulate my variable itself. (If you pass an object it's a whole other story but that deserves a  separate blog post)

This is the same with props! You are just incrementing a copy of the values sent to you. Also it gets a little more complicated with react because the 'render(){}' is meant to be something called a pure function. Simply for you this means each time there is a change in react the stuff inside render is destroyed and rerun from scratch. This means you can't maintain a counter variable inside 'render'.

So we have 2 problems.

1. Find a way to properly maintain a 'state' in the component
2. Find a way to update this state.

This is where React's component state comes in handy!

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
             count : 0;
        }
    }


    render (){
       <Child count={this.state.count}/>
    }
}
```

So now we have found a safe way to maintain the 'state count' in our react component. Next we need a way to update it.  This means the child needs to do some up-word communication to the parent since the state is inside the parent component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
             count : 0;
        }
    }

    increment(){
        this.setState({ counts : this.state.count + 1});
    }   

    render (){
       return(<Child count={this.state.count} increment={this.increment.bind(this)}/>);
    }
}
```

> This is a very powerful concept in react that allows to build reusable components. The Child doesn't know anything about how the parent manages
>   the variable. It is only being passed the current value of the count as well as a
>   function it should call in case the value needs to be incremented.

So in my child I just have to do this...

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    render (){
       <div>
           <div>{this.props.count}</div>
           <button onClick={this.props.increment} >Increment</button>
       </div> 
    }
}
```

You just have to modify this learning in to your app. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a react **Prop** like this. What you need is probably **State**

Prop only got passed from parent to the child component and if a prop is going to be changed, it should happen in the parent component.

Check the difference between State and Props here : https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree about "Check the difference between State and Props here : https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html". But also you should rearrange your components so state and setState will be in one component, because if you don't use Redux the state is local. I would recommend to read this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781

By the way, if you use Redux you can leave your layout and set state via reducers. Now you can update your props when state changed using mapStateToProps.