# Increase state in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In this code, I am trying to increase state itemNumber, but it can't work.
“Cannot update during an existing state transition”

```
  iNumber() {
    this.setState({itemNumber: this.state.itemNumber + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <FlatList data={this.state.dataSource} numColumns={5} renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View>
              {this.iNumber()}
            </View>
          } keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id.toString()} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: When you use setState, you trigger a rerender. What you are doing wrong is calling iNumber(), in the render method. Wich triggers another setState, and then another render call and so on...

Answer (score 0):

`setState` rerenders the UI, so calling `setState` in render makes an infinite loop of rendering, moreover `setState` is asynchronous in nature so, while `isNumber` is being called, the rendering by the previous setState is already in action.

**You should never call `setState` in render**, refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for better understanding about state change and UI rerendering.

Also, in order to keep the cell item number in the state, you might want to consider doing some touch action on the cell and then call the setState using the touch handler. Below is the code snippet showing the same.

```
renderItem={({item}) =>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.iNumber()}>
        <... Ui... />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Or if that's not the case you want, then please help us get your question in a more informative way.

Answer (score 0):

I just need increase state like this:

```
    <FlatList data={this.state.dataSource} numColumns={5} renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.itemNumber++}</Text>
        <Hero title={item.name} square='true />
        {this.state.itemNumber % 5 == 0 ? <Box><TextS>Test</TextS></Box> : null}
      </View>
    } keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id.toString()} />
```

But I do not understand why {this.state.itemNumber++} must be in  component.

Comment: This piece of code is wrong in so many ways.
See whether you understand this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287100/1998725